Nabla operators through differential definitions feel unintuitive in one dimension
In three dimensions, treating the bases $\{\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}\}$ and $\{dx,dy,dz\}$ as "the same", we can find the following four equalities:
$$\nabla=d$$
$$\nabla\times=\star d$$
$$\nabla\cdot=\star d\star$$
$$\nabla^{2}=\star d\star d$$
$d$ is the exterior derivative and $\star$ is the Hodge star, both of which I understand to be linear. This lets us take the nabla operators to any dimension, so let's try one dimension, where $\star1=dx$ and $\star dx=1$.
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$\nabla f=df=f'dx$$
$$\nabla\times f=\star df=\star f'dx=f'\star dx=f'$$
$$\nabla\cdot f=\star d\star f=\star d(f\star 1)=\star d(f dx)=\star 0=0\star1=0dx=0$$
$$\nabla^{2}f=\star d\star d f=\star d\star f'dx=\star d f'\star dx=\star df'=\star f''dx=f''\star dx=f''$$
Both the gradient and Laplacian feel intuitive enough, but it feels to me like the divergence and curl should be switched. Look at the regular definitions.
$$\nabla\cdot(P,Q,R)=\partial_{x}P+\partial_{y}Q+\partial_{z}R$$
$$\nabla\times(P,Q,R)=(\partial_{y}R-\partial_{z}Q)\hat{i}+(\partial_{z}P-\partial_{x}R)\hat{j}+(\partial_{x}Q-\partial_{y}P)\hat{k}$$
To me, it feels like $\nabla\cdot f$ should be essentially the same as
$$\nabla\cdot(f,0,0)=\partial_{x}f+\partial_{y}0+\partial_{z}0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
What's more, $\nabla\times f$ feels like it should be the $dx$ component, the $\hat{i}$ component, of $\nabla\times(f,0,0)$, which is $$\partial_{y}0-\partial_{z}0=0$$
So the curl returns what the divergence feels like, and the divergence returns what the curl feels like. It's possible that I've made some erroneous error with computation or definitions, but if not, why is this the case? Do these final analogies fail to really capture what divergence and curl represent? Is there a better way to think of them, and why they'd behave like this?

Looking around, does it have something to do with those musical isomorphism things, the $#$ and $\flat$ operators? Mine have them omitted, but others don't.

The exterior algebra of a 1D vector space is a 2D space containing scalars and vectors. We have to distinguish between these.
We need to distinguish between the scalar function $f(x)$ and the vector function $\mathbf f(x) = f(x)\,dx$. Note that
$$
  df = f'\,dx \quad\text{but}\quad d\mathbf f = 0
$$
because $\mathbf f$ is a top-form/pseudoscalar.
Keeping in mind that the gradient and Laplacian act on scalar functions while the curl and divergence act on vector functions,
$$
  \nabla f = df = f'\,dx,
$$$$
  \nabla\times\mathbf f = {\star}d\mathbf f = 0,
$$$$
  \nabla\cdot\mathbf f = {\star}d{\star}\mathbf f = {\star}d{\star}(f\,dx) = {\star}df = {\star}(f'\,dx) = f',
$$$$
  \nabla^2f = {\star}d{\star}df = {\star}d{\star}(f'\,dx) = {\star}df' = {\star}(f''\,dx) = f''.
$$

That makes perfect sense. Thanks. My issue is that I'm fairly new to this, so keeping track of all the different spaces seems to evade my skillset.
